# How to take frequencies of different ranges using R?

Tags: r, range, frequency

I have a set of data which refers to Velocities of different people...so my data looks like this
So its basically just a list of velocities

```
Velocity(m/s)
1.2
1.4
2.3
1.6
4.5
3.5
1.7
4.5
3.7
```

I want to use R to get different ranges and the frequency of that particular range...
e.g I want an output similar to the one below

```
Velocity(m/s)     Frequency
1.0 - 3.0            7
1.5- 2.0             4
```

...

So I want to get a frequency column for various ranges. I'm really new to R and would really like to use it to analyse some of my data.

Comment: The ranges are kind of odd

Comment: Could you clarify @LucianoSelzer's comment?

Comment: I'd be happy to up vote upon clarification.

Comment: I will upvote regardless good question

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily with a combination of `cut` and `table`. First lets generate 100 random numbers between 0 & 100:

```
r = runif(100, 0, 100)
```

Next we where we want the breaks to appear. In this example, we want them at: 0, 10, ..., 100:

```
cut(r, breaks=seq(0, 100, 10))
```

Then use the `table` command to calculate the frequency:

```
table(cut(r, breaks=seq(0, 100, 10)))
```

You seem to want overlapping breaks, so I would use the `table` command twice, i.e.

```
t1 = table(cut(r, breaks=seq(0, 100, 10)))
t2 = table(cut(r, breaks=seq(0, 100, 5)))
```

Then combine the results

```
c(t1, t2)
```

Comment: thanks csgillespie....but uhhm I got this error Error in cut.default(f, breaks = seq(0, 4, 2)) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: Without your actual data, it's hard to diagnose wha's wrong. Does my example work for you? In your case, I suspect that `f` has a character in it.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a data.frame with minimum and maximum velocities for each range:

```
my.summary <- data.frame(vel.lo = c(1, 1.5), 
                         vel.hi = c(3, 2))
```

Then use `plyr`'s  `adply` for counting the frequencies:

```
library(plyr)
adply(my.summary, 1, transform, freq = sum(dat$Velocity  > vel.lo &
                                           dat$Velocity <= vel.hi))
#   vel.lo vel.hi freq
# 1    1.0      3    5
# 2    1.5      2    2
```

---

Note: you can also just use the base package's `apply` but since it drops column names, I find `adply` gives you code that reads better than:

```
my.summary$freq <- apply(my.summary, 1, function(x)sum(dat$Velocity  > x[1] &
                                                       dat$Velocity <= x[2]))
```